# Why can't delete the layer1 in the image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Open the image here with photoshop,you can see there is a only 1 layer in the image.Press 'CTRL+T' to activate  the current layer,i can drag and drop it everywhere,the `layer-delete` is gray,you can't select it ,how to delete the layer1?

[image]

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried to fix this?

Comment: Curious if my answer solved your issue @it_is_a_literature

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a layer if it's the only layer.

Try creating a new blank layer and then see if you can delete this one.